# CFDirectory Create on S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, coldfusion

Working on a simple uploader that calls for me to upload to 'user specific' folders, which would need to be created the first time a user uploads something.  All storage is done on S3.  The test code I have at the moment is this (mybucket.domain.name isn't the real bucket, obviously - changed that bit for this posting);

```
<cfif DirectoryExists("s3://mybucket.domain.name/test123/")> 
    <!--- The directory exists --->
<cfelse>
    <!--- Directory doesn't exist, so create it --->
    <cfdirectory action="CREATE" directory="s3://mybucket.domain.name/test123/" storelocation="US">
</cfif>
```

When I run this, no errors are returned - but it always reports the directory not to exist, and never actually creates it.  I've scoured the docs and previous posts here, and as far as I can tell the syntax is correct.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question. Unless the code actually does something inside the cfif condition, it is cleaner to omit it and simply use `<cfif !someCondition>do something</cfif>`

Comment: It will - thats where I'd put the upload code ;-) Valid point though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that S3 doesn't consider anything to be a "folder".  There is no directory tree in S3 -- it's all just objects, and some of those objects happen to have / characters in their names.

There are a couple ways around this, but neither enables you to use directoryExists().

The first way is to evaluate whether the array returned by directoryList('s3://mybucket/foldername') contains any members.

Another way is to do all your S3 operations through a cfc.  Here's one:
https://github.com/joedanz/cf-amazon-s3

If you make your own component that extends that one, you can add to it this function I wrote to accomplish the same thing:

```
<cffunction name="folderExists" access="public" returntype="boolean" hint="folderPath = path/to/folder/ (with trailing slash and no leading slash)">
    <cfargument name="folderPath" type="string" />
    <cfset var objArr = getBucket(bucketName=variables.bucket,prefix='#arguments.folderPath#',delimiter='/') />
    <cfloop array="#objArr#" index="local.o">
        <cfif o.key EQ arguments.folderPath AND o.size EQ 0>
            <cfreturn true />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
    <cfreturn false />
</cffunction>
```

("folderPath" would be "/" if you're looking for a "folder" in the bucket's root.)

*another edit -- you might want this function, too:

```
<cffunction name="folderCreate" access="public" returntype="void">
    <cfargument name="folderPath" type="string" default="" />
    <cfargument name="bucket" type="string" default="#variables.bucket#" />
    <cfif len(folderPath)>
        <cfif right(folderPath,1) NEQ "/">
            <cfset folderPath &= "/" />
        </cfif>
        <cfset putObject(bucketName=bucket,uri=variables.finderPath&URLEncodedFormat(folderPath),contentType='binary/octet-stream') />
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

Explanation: most S3 clients I've seen get around the non-existence of folders by creating zero-length objects and interpreting them as folders.

Comment: thanks for the explanation - oddly, one I haven't seen explained before (unless something has changed recently, numerous examples of DirectoryExists in use with S3 are out there - a post by Raymond Camden being one of the top Google Results).  Assuming I can get around detecting whether it exists, presumably the 'create' should still be working though? (it isn't)

Comment: If you're referring to the same blog post of Ray's that I just looked at, you'll note he uses directoryExists() for the bucket, not for any objects within the bucket.

DirectoryCreate() will have the same problem DirectoryExists() does for the same reason.  This is why they're called 'buckets' in the first place -- because it's just a bucket wherein you dump objects.

Comment: Ahhhh - you know, I completely missed that! Thanks for the heads-up, and I clearly need some coffee!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a "folder" on AWS S3 from ColdFusion, you have to create a 0-length file that has a trailing "/" at the end of its name.

The way I do it is simple using built-in support:

```
 <cffile action = "write"
file = "s3://yourS3bucket/folder_1/" output="">
```

After this is written to your bucket, AWS will report it as a directory and DirectoryExists will work with it (return true) or if you DirectoryList your bucket as a query, this object will be of type DIR. You can also DirectoryCopy to it (though "recurse" doesn't really work as expected with any subdirectories in the source directory.) Note: you will now have an object in your bucket whose key is "folder_1/"